# Suppress environment in mdframed package

Tags: mdframed

I use the Latex package *mdframed* to define "environments" containing headlines and text. 
However, I would like to add some personal notes which should not (!) be displayed, if a boolean variable is set to false. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE.

Comment: the stand art solutin wolul be to resort to any of tje usuall packages ``comment``, ``version``, or ``versions``.
You could also have a look to my answer to this post (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437614) 
to stick with the "boolean variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, finally:

```
%% Define a boolean variable
\newif\ifDisplayToDos
\DisplayToDostrue   % display the toDo-environment 
%\DisplayToDosfalse % uncomment to hide the toDo-environment 

% This will be used below to define an empty environment via \NewEnviron
\usepackage{environ} 

% Depending on the boolean variable, I define the environment:
\ifDisplayToDos
  % define proper environment
  \newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=red]{todo}{ToDo}[section]
\else
  % def. empty environment
  \NewEnviron{todo}{}
\fi
```